# Apply jquery plugin on two button differently on same page

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, form-submit

I wrote a JQuery Plugin to submit a form via ajax. It was working good. But problem arises when I try to use two submit buttons on the same form as below-

```
<form>
    <input type="submit" id="CreateAndExit" value="Create and Exit" />
    <input type="submit" id="CreateAndAdd" value="Create and Add Another" /> 
</form>


$('#CreateAndExit').Save(optionsA);

$('#CreateAndAdd').Save(optionsB);
```

The form is being submitted twice when I click any one button. Any change for one button in `beforeSendFunction()`, applies for other button also.

Here is the structure of my plugin (unnecessary lines are removed)-

```
(function ($) {

$.fn.Save = function (options,validationRules, onBeforeSend, onSuccess, onError, onComplete) {

       return this.each(function () {

        var $This = $(this);

        var settings = $.extend({
           .....
        }, options);

        var $Form;
        if (settings.form == "" || settings.form == "form") {
            $Form = $This.parents('form');
        }
        else {
            $Form = $(settings.form);
        }   

        $This.on('click', function (event) { 
             $Form.submit();
        });

        $Form.on('submit', function (event) { ....  });

        function beforeSendFunction() {
              $This.val('Working…');
              $This.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });
};

}(jQuery));
```

How to overcome this problem?

Comment: what made you think of having 2 submit buttons on same form as you can use click event when you already have id defined...

Comment: So are you already calling `preventDefault()` in the submit event handler?

Answer (score 0):

You probably shouldn't have two submit buttons. But to solve your problem, you problem, you probably need to stop the form from submitting naturally before it does your custom action. Call

```
e.preventDefault();
```

inside the submit or click handler just before calling your `.save()` function

Not only that, but having the submit `click` handler call the form `submit` handler in your code is redundant. Just use the submit handler and delete the submit button click handler.

Comment: unnecessary lines are removed. And I need two buttons.

Comment: Calling `preventDefault` is not unnecessary. :)

Comment: I know that. Thanks.